# Problems with MatrixGrabber: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gles_jni.GLImpl

Tags: android, opengl-es

i have a GLSurfaceView class that must show a square with a texture. I'm trying to fit the screen with the texture/polygon dimensions, then i need to use projections.

I'm using 3 classes to have compatibility with android 1.5:

MatrixGrabber.java
MatrixStack.java
MatrixTrackingGL.java

This is the part of the code that it is giving the error:

```
private MatrixGrabber mg = new MatrixGrabber(); //create the matrix grabber object in your initialization code   
.
.
.
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);      
        screenW=dm.widthPixels;
        screenH=dm.heightPixels;

        modelMatrix=mg.mModelView;
        projMatrix=mg.mProjection;
        mView[0] = 0;
        mView[1] = 0;
        mView[2] = screenW; //width
        mView[3] = screenH; //height    
.
.
.
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {      
        //Clear Screen And Depth Buffer
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);    
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Current Modelview Matrix

        mg.getCurrentProjection(gl);
        mg.getCurrentModelView(gl); 
.
.
.
```

And this is the error:

```
    02-17 09:13:59.952: WARN/dalvikvm(11405): threadid=8: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7e0)
02-17 09:13:59.960: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11405): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 9
02-17 09:13:59.960: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11405): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gles_jni.GLImpl
02-17 09:13:59.960: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11405):     at com.DemoMagazine.MatrixGrabber.getMatrix(MatrixGrabber.java:56)
02-17 09:13:59.960: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11405):     at com.DemoMagazine.MatrixGrabber.getCurrentProjection(MatrixGrabber.java:52)
02-17 09:13:59.960: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11405):     at com.DemoMagazine.SquareGLSurfaceView.onDrawFrame(SquareGLSurfaceView.java:112)
02-17 09:13:59.960: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11405):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1332)
02-17 09:13:59.960: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11405):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1116)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems as well trying to get the matrix, but they seem to be fixed setting the matrixmode to the one i am going to get, in your case:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {      
    //Clear Screen And Depth Buffer
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Current Modelview Matrix

    mg.getCurrentModelView(gl);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    mg.getCurrentProjection(gl);
```

and remember you are now in projection mode, if you need so you can go back to modelview. This worked for me.

Regards!